# Radio buttons and setSelected or something else?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I have a JFrame form with labels, text fields, a combo box and a button group that has 2 radio buttons. In another form I have a JTable filled with data about students (student id, name...), and when I select a row from a table, the form opens and its field need to be filled with same values (eg. if Peter Peterson was selected from the table, then his name should be shown in text filed Name on the form, so I did txtfieldName.setText(student.getName), my question is how do I do this for radio button? Do I need to have yes/no column in the table, so when I select a table row where the value is, say, ''yes'' in order to have yes radio button selected on the form?

Comment: You select the radio button through the group: `group.setSelected(button.getModel(), true);`

Comment: @Josh, you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: @Matthieu As you wish. : )

Answer (score 2):

```
if (result.getString(5).equals("Male")) {
     jRadioButton1.setSelected(true);
} else { 
     jRadioButton2.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

This depends. Is the value that is being applied to the radio button part of the underlying table data (ie from your student object)? If it is, then, no, you don't HAVE to have yes/no column, although it might be of use if you are trying to make decisions on it. Instead, you would simply extract it from the student object.

I would display the yes/no value as a column If it was relevant to the decsion making process.

If the value you want to use to set the radio button is NOT part of the student oect then you need to make some decisions.

Personally, I would create a wrapper object that represented the state of the row, this would include the student object and any other relevant details you might want. This makes the data self contained and makes accessing that information easier.

If that wasnt desirable, then, yes, you would need to probably display the value as a column and maintain it as separate value within the table model.

This will also come down to how you've Implemented the table model

**Updated with feedback from the OP**

Okay, so, with your `student` object hand.  You can get the `boolean` property from the `student` (that is begin represented on the screen by you radio buttons) and make a choice...

```
trueRadioButton.setSelected(booleanValue);
trueRadioButton.setSelected(!booleanValue);
```

You could make it even more simpler by using a `JCheckBox` instead...

```
checkBox.setSelected(booleanValue);
```

Comment: Yes, that value is part of my student object. That is one of the columns in the Student table in my database. When I open my JFrame form, I want button to show values from the database for a particular student(if it's YES in the database, then YES radio button should be selected). I did this for text fields, they work, but I am stuck with radio buttons.

Comment: If txtFieldName.setText(student.getName) is used for text fields, is there something similar to use for radio buttons?

Comment: What is the value of the yes/no value from your studdent object? Is it a Boolean or some other value? How do you distinguish between the value in your student and the radio buttons?

Comment: It's Boolean. Sorry, I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Okay, so armed with the `boolean` property, you need to use that to decide which `JRadioButton` should be selected.  There is no single method you can use to set the whole group.  In fact, it would be eaiser if you used a `JCheckBox` as it only has two (main) states, `true` or `false`, selected or not selected...IMHO - See update

Answer (score 0):

You select the radio buttons through the `ButtonGroup`:

`group.getSelected(button.getModel(), true);`

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to tell which button is selected; I think he's asking whether he _must_ know which one in the group is selected to begin with (answer: he doesn't) to have them in the form.

Comment: I need the buttons in the J from to show me the value from the database. For text fields I use txtFieldName.setText(student.getName()), I am asking how to do this for radio buttons...

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to know which radio button is selected *a priori*, so you don't have to have that information in the table if you don't want to. You can instantiate both radio buttons with the 'selected' parameter set to false:

```
JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("My button label", false);
JRadioButton otherButton = new JRadioButton("My other button label", false);
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(button);
group.add(otherButton);
```

Comment: The things is I have that information in the database, the column that represents buttons has yes/no values. So, I don't want that info in the J table, but when I open my Jframe form, I need the buttons to show the value from the database.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've used custom TableModels to solve this kind of problem. For example, you could load the data from the database into a TableModel implementation that returns values for negative column indices; i.e., getValueAt(row, -1) would give you the desired value for the radio button. The negative columns won't show up in the table, but they'll be accessible to you for getting the data points. e.g., MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel(); Boolean b = (Boolean)model.getValueAt(row, -1); JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("My Button Label", b.booleanValue());

Comment: Let me know if you want me to flesh that previous comment out into a more thorough answer.